# Find 2nd Largest Value Based on Another Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of emails. There can be duplicates or more of the same email. There is another column with dates. I'm wondering if there is a way to create another column indicating which is the 2nd largest date.

```
Email             Date               Second Date?
abc@gmail.com     April 2, 2019      No
abc@gmail.com     April 2, 2019      No
abc@gmail.com     April 15, 2019     Yes
abc@gmail.com     April 15, 2019     Yes
abc@gmail.com     April 28, 2019     No
xyz@gmail.com     April 2, 2019      No
xyz@gmail.com     April 2, 2019      No
xyz@gmail.com     April 24, 2019     Yes
123@gmail.com     April 21, 2019     No
123@gmail.com     April 22, 2019     Yes
```

I'm thinking there might be a way to use the LARGE function, but can't determine how I would look for only the email in that row. Is there a way to combine this function with the SEARCH function?

Answer (score 2):

It was possible, not much sophisticated though. Assuming the range is structured as a table.

```
=IF(MINIFS([Date],[Email],[@Email],[Date],">"&MINIFS([Date],[Email],[@Email]))=[@Date],"Yes","No")
```